# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED in Unix

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED **in Unix** when I use conda command, including update, create a new environment, etc.  I have tried `conda config --set ssl_verify no`, which didn't help. How can I solve this problem?

```
conda version : 4.8.2
conda-build version : 3.18.11
     python version : 3.7.6.final.0
channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
platform : linux-64
```

Comment: Could you please comment on whether it is possible that you have conflicting environment variables set, as mentioned in my reply? I am trying to get some attention paid to this issue, so it would be good to know if your issue has been resolved or not.

Comment: setting REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE (on linux) solved this for me.

Comment: did you fixed this issue? and how?

Answer (score 0):

There have been several reports of this over the past few weeks, but it has been difficult to get anyone with sufficient experience to address them (see [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10111) and [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10146)). I think they assume it is covered by existing advice in the existing [Conda troubleshooting page](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#ssl-connection-errors), but none of those solutions apply to the new crop of issues.

I would recommend running the Conda command with the -v option to find out more details about your problem, and edit your post to include them. You should also add whether you are behind a firewall. Finally, check whether any of the following environment variables are set: PYTHONPATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIRBRARY_PATH. Apparently, this can interfere Conda identifying the SSL module. If they are, try unsetting them and see if that fixes it. In my case, none of them were set so the origin of this is still a mystery.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late. Actually I didn't solve the problem and I just put this down and went to do something else.  Several hours later, without any special configurations, I could use conda commands as usual. BTW,  I didn't set any environment variables you mentioned.